# Print part of page with javascript in Adobe Acrobat

Tags: javascript, adobe, acrobat

I have a fill-in form in Adobe Acrobat with text fields and dropdown boxes.
When the fields are filled, the data go's automatically in a badge-layout with javascript, that stands below the text fields on the same page.

I want to only print the badge file and not the text fields above the badge layout.
Is this possible with javascript? Can this be done with coordinates?

I can only find code to print the full page in javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to print parts. Actually, there are several approaches.

• You create a field (text or button) with white border and filling, set its visibility to "print only" and cover with it everything not to be printed. "covering everything" means that you add this field as the very last one, and set the tab order to "custom" or "not specified". Then you can print normally.

• You crop the page using the `setPageBoxes()` method (details see documentation), print, and then recrop the page to its original size.

The first method will print somewhere on the page, wheras with the second method, you get a "full" page, where you have more control over the printout.